# Why is this Groovy script failing?

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy file with the following 3 statements:

```
def mySillClosure = { null }
def returnValue = mySillClosure.call()
println returnValue
```

This prints

```
null
```

as expected.

If I modify the file and add a closure definition at the end as follows:

```
def mySillClosure = { null }
def returnValue = mySillClosure.call()
println returnValue
{ String foo -> foo.toLowerCase() }
```

I am starting to get:

```
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
    at mygroovy.run(mygroovy.groovy:3)
```

How does defining a closure changing the behaviour for a previous line?

BTW, if I only have the following only in the file, it will run fine - but will not print anything:

```
{ String foo -> foo.toLowerCase() }
```

Comment: There is no definition of the second closure. To define it you have to assign it to some variable `def cl = {...}`. Your syntax tries to call closure over result of previous operation `println` and println returns null.

Comment: The last expression in your snippet is `{ String foo -> foo.toLowerCase() }` which doesn't make any sense by itself.  Did you intend to assign that to a variable or pass it to a method or invoke it?  That expression isn't helpful by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `returnValue` is treated as a method that accepts a closure. In groovy if you omit parentheses ( the last argument is the only argument in this case - its a closure), it will treat this closure like a method argument:

```
println returnValue { String foo -> foo.toLowerCase() }
```

is Basically the same as:

```
println returnValue({String foo -> foo.toLowerCase()})
// its a method that accepts a closure as a parameter
```

But as you said, the method is null by itself, so it can't really call the closure.
For example the following code will do the job:

```
def method(Closure s) {
    s.call("HELLO")
}


println method { String foo -> foo.toLowerCase() }
// or, just the same:
println method({ String foo -> foo.toLowerCase() })
```

Both will print a lower-cased: `hello`

Comment: It's the same as `println(returnValue).call({...})`